# Find sides of triangle, and radius of inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

> $AD = x, \angle A = 60^{\circ}$

I was asked to find $BC$ when $BD=4, CF=2$

I tried using law of cosines, 
$(4+x)^2 + (2+x)^2 - 2(4+x)(2+x) \cos 60^{\circ} = BC^2$

I get $x^2+6x+12=BC^2$

But the answer is $BC= 6, x^2+6x-24=0$

Also i was asked to find $\frac{\triangle ADF}{AG.AE}$. 
I found $\triangle ADF = \frac{\sqrt3}{4}x^2$. But how to find $AG.AE$? Some hints anyone?

Comment: Is $AF$ also equal to $x$?

Comment: I was just assuming by eyeballing the image... it was not informed

Comment: You should never assume anything unless explicitly specified 

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point

Comment: Although in this case, in fact, $AD = AF = x$ because both $AD$ and $AF$ are tangents to the circle from the point $A$.

Comment: How about AG and AE?

Comment: $x =\sqrt{33}-3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard notation: $$BD=\frac{a+c-b}{2}$$ and $$CF=\frac{a+b-c}{2}.$$
Thus, 
$$BC=BD+CF=6.$$
Also, $$\frac{S_{\Delta ADF}}{AG\cdot AE}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}AD\cdot AF\cdot\sin60^{\circ}}{AF^2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Tangents to a circle from the same point, in this case, $BD$ and $BE$ from the point $B$, and $CE$ and $CF$ from the point $C$ have the same lengths. Therefore,

$$BC = BE + EC = BD + CF = 4 + 2 = 6$$

This means the question is giving more than enough information.

Comment: Ok thanks @an4s and all